# Stopping a program in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I debug a code, I can see a stop button. But when I simply run a code, I dont see one. I have to manually kill the terminal or use the task manager to stop the code. Is there any alternative to stop the code(having infinite loops) from running, without having to kill the terminal?

Comment: There is a `workbench.action.tasks.terminate` command you could set to a keybinding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use **Ctrl/Cmd + C** in Windows and Mac respectively. It doesn't kill the terminal but interrupts it for further running.